# Failed to read cached auth token from file "/root/.google_libcloud_auth.gcp-cm-tool"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I can't find the "/root/.google_libcloud_auth.gcp-cm-tool" file in my machine, How to get the file. I used the gcloud command, still it is not created in my home directory (.google_libcloud_auth.${GCE_PROJECT}). Help me with this guys.

Comment: Your question does not have enough details to help you. Start by reading the documentation on how to setup libcloud: https://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html

Comment: You need to add more details in your question. Typically, what's your machine, can you confirm it's a GCE machine? Also what was the gcloud command that you used?